# URL Routing in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to get into Angular 2, and I've gotten a working router running.  The issue is that it only works when you click a `router-link`.  If I go directly to the path then it brings up the root template, `/`.  Here's what it looks like currently;

```
import { routerInjectables, RouteConfig, RouterOutlet, RouterLink } from 'angular2/router';

.
.
.

@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: HelloComponent, as: 'hello' },
  { path: '/goodbye', component: GoodbyeComponent, as: 'goodbye' }
])
```

UPDATE: Here's a gist with the full code: https://gist.github.com/trezm/bc0ea506b610c7306b50

Comment: Maybe show the full example? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: This may be useful https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3096